Is there a spell checker for VS Code for the OLD (1901) German spelling rules?
In general, I know how to enable spell checking in VS Code for different languages. However, I was not able so far to find a spell checker for the old German spelling rules (sometimes called 1901 rules).
To clarify, the following link shows such a dictionary for LibreOffice:
https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/german-de-de-1901-old-spelling-dictionaries
I'd like to have such a dictionary in VS Code. Any idea where I can get it from?

FYI - Hunspell is the spell checker behind libre office and, if not natively supported by VS Code, I would bet on there being an extension that does. Check out the repo for the de-DE-1901 dictionary.

I see. Thank you. I know Hunspell, but didn't come to the idea that I could integrate it with VS Code.
